# bash: tslint: command not found

Tags: javascript, typescript, tslint

I tried use `tslint --fix` but get `bash: tslint: command not found...`.

I installed tslint using command: `yarn global add tslint typescript`.

My machine use Centos 7.

Comment: what is output of `yarn global add tslint typescript` ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I've run into the same problem recently. `Yarn` output says it added `"tslint"` binary, but it's lying. To actually install it you need to run `Yarn` as root, so:

```
sudo yarn global add tslint typescript
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works please update the answer with source URL as well.Thanks
 https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/cli/

Answer (score 4):

I needed to delete the /node_modules folder and run npm install and it was fixed again